# Retrieve only data from snapshot present in ArrayList firebase android

Tags: android, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have 2 arraylist. one of contact list present in my phone book, and other of phone numbers in my database.

**Getting contacts from PhoneBook.**

```
    private void getArrayListDataFromPhonebook(ContentResolver contentResolver) {
//        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

        Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, ContactsContract.Contacts.SORT_KEY_PRIMARY + " ASC");
        if (cursor != null) {
            HashSet<String> mobileNoSet = new HashSet<String>();
            try {
                final int nameIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);
                final int numberIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);

                String name, number;
                while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                    name = cursor.getString(nameIndex);
                    number = cursor.getString(numberIndex);
                    number = number.replace(" ", "");
                    if (!mobileNoSet.contains(number)) {
//                        contactListFromPhoneBook.add(new Contact(name, number));


                        contactListFromPhoneBook.add(number);
                        Log.d("contact", String.valueOf(contactListFromPhoneBook.size()));

                        mobileNoSet.add(number);
                    }
                }
            } finally {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

**Getting contact From firebase database and comparing with phonebook from my Mobile**

```
private void getCommonContact(){

ArrayList<String> contactList = new ArrayList<>();
Set<String> set1 = new HashSet<>();
Set<String> set2 = new HashSet<>();

FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference;

mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

mDatabaseReference = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("users");

Query myQuery = mDatabaseReference.orderByChild("username");
myQuery.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


        for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

            String number = "" + snapshot.child("phone").getValue();
            contactList.add(number);

            for (String i : contactList) {
                set1.add(i);
            }

            for (String i : contactListFromPhoneBook) {
                set2.add(i);
            }

            set1.retainAll(set2);
            set1.add(number);

            Log.d("set1", String.valueOf(set1));




            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (String s : set1)
            {
                sb.append(s);
                sb.append("\t");
            }

            System.out.println(sb.toString());

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

}

**Log.d("set1", String.valueOf(set1));**

```
D/set1: [+918460883852, +919045810005, +917383085422, +919875142541, +919856257129, +919112546330, +919930325611]
```

I am getting all the contact present in firebase database
All i want is to compare set1 with firebase database and get the common number in recyclerview
my Holders in bindviewholder are:- holder.mTvUsername  , holder.Tvcontact.
my recycler

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: i Dont have any error. I have an hashset Set1 which consists of data compared from my phone contacts and firebase contact . So i only want to retreive data from firebase present in set1. and show them in recyclerview. It would be great if u can help.

Comment: What part of the existing code, doesn't do what you expect to do it?